# Rufus scheduler running multiple times with unicorn, fixed with :lockfile, but how to eliminate the error msg?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, rufus-scheduler

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new :lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock"

scheduler.every("60") do
...
end
```

Environment: Ubuntu, rails 4, rufus, unicorn, nginx

Unicorn has multiple workers, so the above 'every' task will be executed multiple times every 60 seconds.

According to the answer for this one:
    [rufus scheduler running twice each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710821/rufus-scheduler-running-twice-each-time)
, I added :lockfile option, and it works!

However, from the log, it seems that the 'every' task still tries to be called, resulting in a lot of error messages:

```
E, [2014-05-09T01:59:47.496840 #2747] ERROR -- : cannot schedule, scheduler is down or shutting down (Rufus::Scheduler::NotRunningError)
/home/sohmobile/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.7/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:605:in `do_schedule'
/home/sohmobile/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.7/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:209:in `every'
/home/sohmobile/releases/20140509014407/config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This could solve your issue:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler.lock")

unless scheduler.down?

  scheduler.every("60") do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: If that's the case, then accept my answer and vote it up. Thanks in advance :-)